# Can interface block size be larger than underlying UBO in Opengl?

Tags: opengl, glsl, language-lawyer

Let's declare a large interface block in a shader:

```glsl
struct InstancingData
{
    // whatever
};

#define LARGE_SIZE 1048576
layout(std140, row_major, binding = 0) uniform InstanceBlock
{
    InstancingData data[LARGE_SIZE];
};
```

Then I want to bind a small UBO, containing less than `LARGE_SIZE` entries of `InstancingData` to this block. It may be either `glBingBufferBase` of a small array, or `glBindBufferRange` of a small range within a larger array.

Consequently, I will index `data` only with indices smaller than underlying buffer size allows, using an appropriate uniform or `gl_VertexID`. So formally it shouldn't lead to access violation.

Will these actions trigger an error or undefined behavior in any OpenGL version?

**Another way to go:**

I declared

```glsl
InstancingData data[1];
```

Then I bound a buffer of 42 structures and indexed all of them (a 6x7 square bed of instanced models), and it worked fine on my machine. Is it guaranteed to work anywhere?

Comment: @Rabbid76 No way. I'm restricted to OGL 3.3 core.

Comment: @Sergey: There is no GL 3.3-only hardware that allows you to have a UBO of over 4 million bytes. And technically, that UBO would be at least 16 million bytes in size, by the rules of `std140` array layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ARB_uniform_buffer_object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_uniform_buffer_object.txt):

> If any active uniform block is not backed by a sufficiently large
>   buffer object, the results of shader execution are undefined, and may
>   result in GL interruption or termination.

This is sufficient to say that backing `InstancingData data[LARGE_SIZE];` with a small buffer is illegal.

Comment: The same wording can be found at the end of 2.11.4 of the [GL 3.3 Core Profile spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec33.core.pdf)

Comment: Either you fill the rest of the buffer with something (e.g. 0) or better split the UB into small pieces that fit your different cases.

Comment: @Ripi2 Splitting UBO into small pieces is not always better, as in my case it will increase number of draw calls.